# Huge DIV but make it so you can't scroll down to the bottom of it

Tags: html, css

So let's say I have a div element a and a div element b and div element a is flot: left of b. I want to make it so element a is huge, but it doesn't influence scrolling. By that I mean that if div b gets bigger, you can scroll to the bottom of it, but if div a gets bigger, just ignore it and you cant scroll to the bottm of it.

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried overflow: hidden but that makes it so even when div b gets bigger, you cant scroll to the bottm of it. I couldn't find anything else than that.

Comment: we need more information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this, hope it will resolve your issue**

```css
body{
    height:100%;
    }
.container{
    height:100%;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0px;
    }
    .a{background:red;overflow:hidden; width:30%; height:100%; display:inline-block; float:left}
    .b{background:blue;overflow:auto; width:65%; height:100%; display:inline-block; float:left}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
    <div class="a">content of a, it will not scroll
      <br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/><br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/><br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text
      text<br/>
      text
      </div>
    <div class="b"> content of b, insert as much content, it will scroll
<br/>
      text
      <br/>
      text
      <br/>
      text
      <br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/><br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text<br/>
      text
      <br/>
      text
      <br/>
      text
      <br/>
      text
      <br/>
      text
      <br/>
      text
      


</div> 
    </div>
```